# How to make a website like tryRuby, tryJquery, etc. (terminal inside your website)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm hoping to make a side project that implements a terminal inside of your website and create questions for other people a la codeschool, codeacademy, and treehouse. Making it look like a terminal with CSS and doing some programming to interpret it right isn't so much a problem. More like I'm hoping for some tips, gems, links etc. that will help me get started, save me some time, and make it look more professional. Hope this is a good question, I'm still learning my way around the community :).

Comment: https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby

Comment: http://terminal.jcubic.pl